# How to get URL in Photo Library?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am picking a video and I want to upload it to Firebase but there is an error in my code. I think the error is because of the URL. I tried lots of methods to get the URL but nothing worked.

This is my code below:

```
@IBAction func showImagePicker() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    picker.videoQuality = .typeIFrame1280x720
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    let videoName = UUID().uuidString
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent(videoName)

    print("videoName: \(videoName)")
    print("url: \(url)")
    
    let metadata = StorageMetadata() //get metadata of firebase
    metadata.contentType = "video/quicktime"
    let storageRef = storage.reference() //get storage reference of the firebase storage
    
    let videoRef = storageRef.child("videos/\(videoName)") //Get a folder where the video will be saved
    
    videoRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in //uploading to the firebase storage folder
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            //If there is error in meta data, print "error"
            print("error\(error)")
            return
        }
        print("Put us complete and I got this back: \(String(describing: metadata))")
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
        let size = metadata.size
        
        // Access to download URL after upload.
        videoRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                print("Got an generating the URL:)")
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                return
            }
        }
    }

    print("Done")
}
```

This is the error below:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "File at URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BE603CC-A936-43CF-8127-EB224EC0D7ED/Documents/96267AEB-F61D-4985-8C6D-FD641DEAD72D is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=File at URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BE603CC-A936-43CF-8127-EB224EC0D7ED/Documents/96267AEB-F61D-4985-8C6D-FD641DEAD72D is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url.})

I want to upload the selected video to Firebase storage.

Comment: You have created a URL in your documents directory, but you haven't actually saved the supplied image to that file, so the file doesn't exist - Which is the error you are getting.  You need to get the original or edited image from the `info` dictionary and save it into the file before you attempt to upload

Comment: You should also write the file extension .mp4 with video name "\(videoName).mp4"

Answer (score 0):

I had done uploading videos to Firebase Storage recently. Try this:

For **Video Picker**:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct VideoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var onVideoPicked : (URL, String) -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .videos
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, onVideoPicked: self.onVideoPicked)
    }
    
    class Coordinator:NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate{
        
        let parent:VideoPicker
        var onVideoPicked : (URL, String) -> Void
        
        init(_ parent: VideoPicker, onVideoPicked: @escaping (URL, String) -> Void){
            self.parent = parent
            self.onVideoPicked = onVideoPicked
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
                // do something on dismiss
            }
            
            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else {return}
            provider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.movie") { url, error in
                guard error == nil else{
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                    return
                }
                // receiving the video-local-URL / filepath
                guard let url = url else {return}
                // create a new filename
                let fileName = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).\(url.pathExtension)"
                // create new URL
                let newUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + fileName)
                // copy item to APP Storage
                try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: newUrl)

                self.onVideoPicked(newUrl, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return your **video URL** and the **video name**

Use this in SwiftUIView as:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $vm.openVideos, content: {
         VideoPicker(onVideoPicked: { url, videoName in
 
         let videoRef = storageRef.child("videos/\(videoName)")
                    
         videoRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
            
            if error != nil {
                Helper.shared.printDebug("\(String(describing: error)) and \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")")
                return
            }
            
            videoRef.downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
                guard let url = url else {
                    print("Failed to get download url")
                    return
                } 

                print(url.absoluteString)
           })
         }  
     })
})
```